# QM - calculating expectation value for velocity of an electron

Tags: quantum-mechanics

How do we calculate the expectation value for speed? I have heard that we must first calculate the expectaion value for kinetic energy. Someone please explain a bit what options do we have.

Comment: Well i asked this because I cant find an anwser in my book which only describes operators of kinetic energy, potential energy, momentum, position and position square... If i write expectation value for speed, [Google returns](https://www.google.si/search?q=expectation+value+for+speed&oq=expectation+value+for+speed&aqs=chrome.0.69i57.4077j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) mostly these same operators...

Comment: Never mind I found it in [this PDF](http://physics.mq.edu.au/~jcresser/Phys201/LectureNotes/ProbabilitiesExpectationValues.pdf) - page 32 - Now give me some downvotes for being lazy :D

Comment: I have discovered that in this PDF they diferentiate the wavefunction over time but i have a stationary state! Do i have to multiply it with $\exp\frac{i}{\hbar E t}$ and then diferentiate it? **Is there any easier way if i already calculated expectation value for kinetic energy $\langle T \rangle$?**

Comment: You can't derive a vector ($\vec v$) from its square ($T\sim v^2$)

Comment: So this is not possible?  $\langle E_k\rangle = \tfrac{1}{2}m\langle v \rangle^2 \longrightarrow \langle v\rangle = \sqrt{2 \langle E_k \rangle / m}$

Comment: Well if you want just magnitude of velocity, then it's possible.

Comment: I will be satisfied with only a magnitude so far ... don-t know enough of QM yet to think about QM vectors :). Do zou think this classical approximation is good enough for a particle in a box. I mean i calculated $\langle E_k \rangle=338.79eV$.

Comment: I think this still isn't quite good (compare $\sqrt{\left<v^2\right>}$ with $\left<|v|\right>$ for some random set of $v$), you'd better compute it from velocity operator not from kinetic energy.

Comment: After looking at @Ali's anwser I believe that you meant **"momentum operator"** instead of the **"velocity operator"**. Thanks for pointing this out as i wasn't sure if i d get $\langle v \rangle^2$ or $\rangle v^2 \langle$ using the kinetic energy method - i guess it is the later huh - can i ask you, how do we know this? Why do we know that by using the kinetic energy method we get $\langle v^2\rangle$ and not $\langle v\rangle^ 2$? For the solution i will take Ali-s anwser.

Comment: We know that we get $\left<v^2\right>$ because we find expectation value of $\frac{\hat p^2}{m^2}$ not $\frac{|\hat{\vec p}|}{m}$.

Comment: While both the question and the selected answer seem to be conflating them, the expectation values of velocity and speed are not the same thing.For any sufficiently symmetric bound system $\langle v \rangle = 0$ while $\langle |v| \rangle > 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculating the energy eigenvalue, will give you $\langle v^2 \rangle$. This is how it's done:

$$\langle v^2 \rangle = \frac{2}{m}\langle T \rangle=\frac{2}{m}\langle \psi|\hat T|\psi\rangle=\frac{2}{m}\int\psi^*(x)\hat T \psi(x)dx$$

Where you should write $T$(the kinematic energy) as an [operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_operator). This can be done by writing it as a function of $x$ and $p$, and then replacing $p$ with its operator.

**However this is not what we call the expectation value of speed**. To calculate the expectation value of speed, we calculate the expectation value of its momentum:

$$\langle v \rangle = \frac{\langle  p\rangle}{m}=\frac{1}{m}\int \psi^*(x)p\psi(x)dx$$

Which can be calculated either by transforming $\psi$ to the momentum space, or replacing $p$ with its [operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum_operator) $-\mathfrak i \hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$.

An important thing to note is: $\langle v^2 \rangle \ne \langle v\rangle^2$ in general. E.g. consider the symmetric harmonic potential where $\langle v \rangle=0$ but $\langle v^2 \rangle > 0$. The difference is called [variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) $\sigma_v^2=\langle v^2 \rangle-\langle v \rangle^2$.

Comment: Regarding your 1st paragraph. Why did you use the energy $\langle E \rangle$ and an operator $\hat{H}$ instead of $\langle E_k \rangle$ and an operator $\langle \hat{T}\rangle$?

Comment: Oops, that's a mistake.